# best encryption using IP as key

Tags: node.js, encryption, ip-address

Im working on a project involving the encryption of 64 character strings, the key is going to be an IP. I don't know what type of IP will be inputted by the user. I need something very secure, but It needs to be decryptable. Hashing is not a option for a few reasons. Currently im looking at blowfish and twofish, however they are apparently not so secure. The amount of time It takes to encrypt/decrypt does not matter. Anything under 20s. Does anyone know of any good methods?
P.S: im using nodeJS
Thanks

EDIT:
By IP I mean Internet Protocol (IP) address.
and the strings are 64 characters long.

Comment: What is `IP` in this context? The tag says "Internet Protocol" or "Intellectual Property", but neither make much sense in context. And does `64 character strings` mean 64 bytes long strings?

Comment: fixed, added edit

Comment: IP addresses are 32 bits and not very random, which will be trivial to brute force. Blowfish and Twofish are secure, but your weak point is choosing the IP address as the key. A more detailed answer might be found at [security.se] or [crypto.se].

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that I have to use an IP address as the key. My other option is to sha256 the IP address and use the hashed IP as the key.

Comment: You don't invent key derivation algorithms, but use something already existing: eg pbkdf2

Comment: If the key isn't very safe, then the encryption algorithm doesn't really matter much.  That's kind of like investing thousands of dollars in a really, really strong lock for your front door, but the key is under the front doormat so it matters not how string the lock is.

Comment: An IP address have way to little "random" data to serve as a key, and putting it through a sha256 don't add more randomness.

Comment: you can use any reasonable library (such as crypto-js), blowfish is secure enough, but choosing IP is really not secure (if someone asks that from you, tell them it's really NOT secure).